# Can JavaScript get confused between local variables?

Tags: javascript

If I have a pair of functions that both set local variables, for example, the variable `i` in common `for` loops, and one happens to be called while the other is running, is there any danger of namespace confusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're using `var`, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < something; i++)
```

Then it's local and you're fine, if you *don't* use `var`, you have a global variable on your hands, and potential issues.  Also if a `for` loop is *nested* in another, you should use a different variable name for each loop.

Answer (score 11):

Keep in mind that JavaScript does not have block scope, but only function scope.

In addition, if you have nested loops, there will only be one `i` variable in the following example:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      // code here will run 10 times instead of 100 times
    }
  }
  // variable i is still accessible from here
}
```

[Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) recommends that the `var` statements should be the first statements in the function body in [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations):

> JavaScript does not have block scope, so defining variables in blocks can confuse programmers who are experienced with other C family languages. Define all variables at the top of the function.

I think he has a point, as you can see in the following example, which will not confuse readers into thinking that the variables `i` and `j` are held in the scope of the `for` loop blocks:

```
function myFunction() {
  var i, j;    // the scope of the variables is now very clear
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      // code here will run 100 times
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first example break the script as `var i` is called twice?

Comment: @Isaac: No, JavaScript will simply ignore the variable declaration, if a variable is declared twice as in my first example. Obviously, the loops will not work as intended in that example, since the inner loop will increment the control variable of the outer loop.

Comment: Simple test case of first example to prove that Daniel is right: http://jsfiddle.net/sAg8P/2/

Answer (score 0):

It will be a problem if are you referring to nested loops. Every time you enter the second for loop, the value of i (previously set in the outer for loop) will be reset.